# How to operationalize a decision tree in a cloud environment?

Tags: cloud, decision-tree

I have to deal with the situation that I have a decision tree that needs to be run within a chatbot. So, the idea for it was to have a microservice that takes the user input from the chatbot, runs the logic of the decision tree, and sends an output to the chatbot.

However, I studied a lot of methods how to build a decision tree at grad school but never ever I have learnt how to operationalize such a model in an engine in the cloud.

I'd be so grateful about any kind of hint where I could look at to find a way how to build an engine that runs the logic of the decision tree in a cloud environment. I do have a coworker who is experienced in the chatbot system such that I would receive any kind of data input that is required for the engine from the chatbot. For the response from the engine, I would need some kind of JSON or XML to be sent to the chatbot system.

One of the core ideas is not to handle the decision tree within the chatbot because that is where we were at the moment and it did not work out well. I would like to have an engine that runs the decision tree regardless of the chatbot system.

What could I use for such an engine for a decision tree?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on nature of this decision tree, but in general if you want to implement branched workflow with Lambdas or other AWS services, take a look at [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/)